# default locale and numberformat

Tags: java, localization

Hi I am struggling to format numbers like the documentation for NumberFormat.getInstance() says. 
(Windows 7, NetBeans, Java 7)

I have first gone into regional settings and removed us english, us english keyboards and everything. I set it all to French and France. I even rebooted my pc. My code is:

```
System.setProperty("user.language", "fr");
System.setProperty("user.country", "FR");
System.setProperty("user.language.display", "fr");
System.setProperty("user.country.display", "FR");
System.setProperty("user.language.format", "fr");
System.setProperty("user.country.format", "FR");
Locale locale = new Locale("French", "France");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Locale.setDefault(Locale.Category.DISPLAY, locale);
Locale.setDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT, locale);
java.text.NumberFormat nf = java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance();
System.out.println(nf.format(4.5));
```

Despite all of this, the program prints "4.5". I don't understand, for French France this should be "4,5". What more do I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("French", "France");
```

It should be:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("fr", "FR");
```

Or just use `Locale.FRENCH`.

Additionally, you don't need to set any properties or change the default locale. Just fetch the `NumberFormat` for the locale you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

It's a lot easier than that...

```
    Locale locale = Locale.FRENCH;
```

will initialize the variable with the french locale, and

```
    java.text.NumberFormat nf = java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
```

will get you a NumberFormat for that locale.

EDIT: as you're using NetBeans, two tips to avoid this kind of trouble in the future:

When you type

```
    Locale locale = new Locale(
```

followed by ctrl-space NetBeans will pop up a list of possible completions of that statement, with for each alternative a small window showing the JavaDoc.

Alternatively, when the cursor is on `Locale` NetBeans will bring up a browser window with the JavaDoc when you press Alt-F1 or rightclick, Show JavaDoc.

Java's library is well documented, and having the documentation come up with just one keystroke is a real timesaver.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but I would like to report I've just found what seems to be a bug in the JVM implementation for OSX (Mac only bug).

This is a small piece of code that shows the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DecimalFormatSymbols d = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT));

    System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.language.format"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.language"));
    System.out.println(d.getDecimalSeparator());
    System.out.println(d.getGroupingSeparator());

    Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
    System.out.println("Language: "+l.getLanguage());
    System.out.println("Country: "+l.getCountry());
    System.out.println("Variant: "+l.getVariant());
    System.out.println("Tag: "+l.toLanguageTag());
    Currency c = Currency.getInstance(l);
    System.out.println("Code: "+c.getCurrencyCode());
    NumberFormat nc = DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    NumberFormat ni = DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance();

}
```

In my case, the output is:

```
en
es
.
,
Language: es
Country: ES
Variant: 
Tag: es-ES
Code: EUR
```

Im my operating system I've set es_ES but due to a bug. The JVM system property `user.language.format` is not properly initialised and this is the source of several pains.